Using custom certificates for MTLS in Strimzi Kafka
I am trying to bring up the Kafka cluster using Strimzi operator with MTLS configured for external clients. I have the CA certificates from Let's Encrypt. I also have the public certificate (issued by the CA) and private keys for my server and client. I am trying to follow the Strimzi documentation https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/deploying.html#installing-your-own-ca-certificates-str.
Configuring the <cluster_name>-cluster-ca-cert and <cluster_name>-clients-ca-cert is clear. Since I have the CA certificates for both client and server I can configure.
But I am not sure how to configure the <cluster_name>-cluster-ca and <cluster_name>-clients-ca. Both of them needs private keys of the corresponding CA which is not available in my case as the CA is a third party. But without this my Kafka cluster is not coming up (as I have made generateCertificateAuthority as false for both clusterCa and ClientCa).
I tried providing the private keys of server and client to <cluster_name>-cluster-ca and <cluster_name>-clients-ca respectively (though incorrect) and it did not work as expected. Strimzi operator tries to sign certificates using the private keys and it fails. I am now stuck at this point and not able to proceed with my MTLS configuration. I tried using the latest version of Strimzi operator (0.45.0).
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Duplicate of / Answered in https://github.com/orgs/strimzi/discussions/10991

Thanks @Jakub for answering the questions in the discussion https://github.com/orgs/strimzi/discussions/10991
